# How can I change the terminal line spacing in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

This is currently what my terminal looks like in idea.  I've tried Jacking up and down the Line spacing property in `Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Console Font`  I've tried it with Meslo LG L DZ and Consolas and it there is no change to line spacing with either.

Is there something I'm missing about changing the look of the terminal?

Also, here is all the relevant info about my idea installation:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-183.5429.30, built on January 28, 2019
Licensed to IntelliJ IDEA Evaluator
Expiration date: March 21, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b26 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Comment: It's a known limitation: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-201379.

Answer (score 9):

In the recently released IntelliJ IDEA version 2019.3 this works. I did a short test and could see the effect of changing the line spacing. I also could see "Fix versions" in the issue mentioned in CrazyCoder's comment is set to 2019.3.

Comment: can you share some example

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking for and I don't understand why this answer is downvoted. It contains the solution to the question by telling anyone interested that the requested feature is available in the newest IntelliJ version. Just upgrade to the newest IntelliJ version 2019.3, do what the original author describes (change the settings for line spacing in IntelliJ) and you will immediately see the effect on a open terminal. I don't know what kind of example I could provide you. A screencast?

Comment: I have the same issue, but a little more insight now.
The terminal *does* take the font, font size, and line spacing, but the line spacing is limited to a minimum of 0.9 or so. If you specify values below, in the editor it works, but in the terminal, it does not.